# Concatenação de uma arrayList em uma listView?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de adicionar **"strings"** a serem exibidas em um **listView** de forma que eu não tenha de ficar impondo condições e mais condições e setando novamente as **"strings"** já utilizadas:

```
package genesysgeneration.list;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btnEspada, btnArco;
    private ListView lvItens;
    private int cont01, cont02;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cont01=0;
        cont02=0;

        lvItens=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvItens);
        btnEspada=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEspada);
        btnArco=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnArco);

        btnEspada.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnArco.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        final ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> itens = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, item);

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btnEspada:

                if (cont01==0){

                    cont01=1;

                    if (cont02==1){

                        item.add("Espada");
                        item.add("Arco");
                        lvItens.setAdapter(itens);

                    }else {

                        item.add("Espada");
                        lvItens.setAdapter(itens);

                    }

                }else {

                    cont01=0;

                    if (cont02==1){

                        item.add("Arco");
                        lvItens.setAdapter(itens);

                    }else {

                        item.add("");
                        lvItens.setAdapter(itens);

                    }

                }

                break;

            case R.id.btnArco:

                if (cont02==0){

                    cont02=1;

                    if (cont01==1){

                        item.add("Espada");
                        item.add("Arco");
                        lvItens.setAdapter(itens);

                    }else {

                        item.add("Arco");
                        lvItens.setAdapter(itens);

                    }

                }else {

                    cont02=0;

                    if (cont01==1){

                        item.add("Espada");
                        lvItens.setAdapter(itens);

                    }else {

                        item.add("");
                        lvItens.setAdapter(itens);

                    }

                }

                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Algo simples, exemplo: Já existem 10 itens exibidos na minha listView. Eu gostaria de adicionar mais itens sem ter de setar todos os outros (`item.add(item01), item.add(item02) ...`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o ArrayList está a ser criada sempre que o botão é clicado.

Declare-o como um atributo da classe, instancie-o no onCreate() e construa aí também o Adapter.

Em cada `case` do método `onClick()` chame o método `add()` com o respectivo valor.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btnEspada, btnArco;
    private ListView lvItens;
    private ArrayList<String> itens;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itensAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvItens=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvItens);
        btnEspada=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEspada);
        btnArco=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnArco);

        btnEspada.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnArco.setOnClickListener(this);

        itens = new ArrayList<String>();
        itensAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, itens);
        lvItens.setAdapter(itensAdapter);    
    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btnEspada:

                itens.add("Espada");
                itensAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;

            case R.id.btnArco:

                itens.add("Arco");
                itensAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A lógica de inserção no listview é a seguinte:

1. crie um adapter e set no listview `listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, new ArrayList<>()))` no onCreate()
2. Ao recuperar o listener de algum botao, use este código para adicionar algum item no listView:

   ```
   lvItens.getAdapter().add("Teste");
   lvItens.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notifica a listView que os dados mudaram e necessita atualizar o view com eles
   ```

Repita este processo para cada Listener e pronto, terá uma listView com itens que os botões adicionaram. Contudo, desta forma, você pode repetir dados na lista, caso não queira isso, verifique antes, se existe o elemento na lista, olhando dentro de um `for` ou loop.

Comment: Não, tipo... eu gostaria de não ter de utilizar essas condições que implementei "if". Uma forma onde ao clicar no button, ele adicionasse o item ao final do listView independente do que houvesse já no listView

Comment: Não intendi a lógica destas condições, o porque delas ? Você gostaria de clicar em um botão e adicionar uma string no array, caso já tiver a string, não fazer nada, e cada botão teria uma String para adicionar ?

Comment: Não. Esqueça esse "if's", gostaria de saber somente como fazer para adicionar strings ao listView.

Quando não coloco essas condições, e clico no button, o listView aparece somente o último button clicado. Gostaria de saber como fazer (por exemplo) para que se a activity tiver 10 buttons, e eu clicar nos 10, apareçam 10 itens no listView.

Comment: Acho que compreendi agora.